# Access the struct elements without defining cases for each element if the position of the element in structure is known

Tags: c, pointers, struct

If i have a structure with 3 elements and a read request comes for the first element. In this scenario is there a way of reading that structures Xth element in a common manner without defining cases for each of the number.

sample psuedo code

```
#define RED 1
#define BLUE 2
#define GREEN 3

typedef struct color
{
int red;
int char;
int green;
};

color a1;
void ReadfromColor(int id , void * abc)
{
switch(id)
{
case RED:
{
 temp = a1.red;
}
break;

case BLUE:
{
 temp = a1.blue;
}
break;

case GREEN:
{
 temp = a1.green;
}
break;

abc=&temp;
}
```

}

Here for each element i have a case. So if the elements and the order is known to the function ReadfromColor, is there a common way so as to refer the particular property for the structure?

//This may be a foolish question still hoping for a way out of it.....

Answer (score 1):

you could change the representation to:

```
typedef struct color {
  int c[3]; // int[0] is red, green, blue
} color_t;
```

access inside the function:

```
temp = c[id];
```

Comment: In the real code the problem is the structures are standard which cannot be changed

Comment: maybe you could use `offsetof()` to find out the offsets and use `id` as an offset into the struct (but you need to take care about alignment and signedness): e.g. `abc=a1+id*sizeof(int)`

Comment: jev certainly meant `abc = &a1.red+id-1`.